# Key board doesn't appear in UIWebView after showing window.alert in iPhone

Tags: iphone, .net, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

In my `UIWebView`, key board doesn't appear on text box after showing `window.alert` in the web page. Actual senario is,

- **step 1:** open my application and view our web page in `UIWebView`.
- **Step 2:** Showing alert when I press the button on web page.
- **Step 3:** I doesn't response to the alert and press the screen lock
  button.
- **Step 4:** Release the screen lock and press the 'OK' button in `window.alert`.
- **Step 5:** Page reloading after pressing 'OK' button. After that I pressing the text box, key board doesn't appear on the screen.

I can't get exact solution for this. May I know what is the issue and how to resolve this issue?

Note: without showing `window.alert`, its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is try this:

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

A similar question referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954003/keyboard-does-not-appear-in-the-uiwebview-on-the-uinavigationcontroller).

Comment: Yeah. I used. But still I have that problem.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. You need to provide a simple sample project that just reproduces the issue.

Comment: But you have to place that in the appDelegate, in the LaunchWithOptions method.

Answer (score 1):

Check your AppDelegate's window.windowLevel - to normally handle interaction with web controls it should be set to UIWindowLevelNormal.

Answer (score 1):

Do the keyboard delegate methods (e.g. textFieldShouldBeginEditing) get called at all? Have you tried calling becomeFirstResponder manually to see if it responds?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities :

- you could try to call on page load `[self.webView endEditing:YES];` as it forces first responder + keyboard to fully close
- otherwise, if it's also interesting for you to have a nicer Alert (without the page name as alert title), you could use shouldStartLoadWithRequest to intercept a custom request, and display a native UIAlertView based on this (tell me if you need sample code)